# How to make for loop in JavaScript synchronous

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to iterate an array in Javascript and one element will take some time to get processed.

I want to till that element is processed, wait for that.

```js
var splittedText = ["Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You", "Today"];
var text = "";

splittedText.forEach((name) => {
  if (name === "Are") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      text = text + "ARE"
    }, 2000)
  } else {
    text = text + name + " ";
  }
  console.log(text)
});
```

**Expected Output** - Hello World How ARE You Today.

**Actual** - Hello World How You Today

Comment: You've specifically made it **A**synchronous by introducing a `setTimeout`. Remove that and its synchronous again. What are you _really_ asking? This hints heavily at an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - are you asking how to wait in the loop for an async action to complete?

Comment: You can't make a `forEach` loop synchronous. It ignores the return value and calls the next function after the current function returned.

Comment: @ThomasSablik a `forEach` is still synchronous though?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, `forEach` is synchronous. But not the functions inside. And you can't make `forEach` wait for an async function.

Comment: @jamiec Yes, I purposely used setTimeout. I want to know how to wait in the loop for an async action to complete

Comment: @ThomasSablik Pls suggest another approach.

Comment: Don't use a `forEach` loop. Use a `for ... of ...` loop instead.

Comment: So your title is misleading then - you're not asking how to make a loop synchronous (they already are!!), you're asking how to wait for an asynchronous action in a loop.  For which there are about a million duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a `forEach` loop wait for an asynchronous function. It ignores the return value and calls the next function after the current function returned. You can use a `for ... of ...` loop and await the promise. But `await` can only be used inside an `async` function (or inside an `async` IIFE).

```js
(async function() {
    const splittedText = ["Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You", "Today"];
    let text ="";

    for (const name of splittedText) {
        if (name === "Are") {
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    text = text + "ARE";
                    resolve();
                }, 2000);
            });
        } else {
            text += name + " ";
        }  
        console.log(text)
    };
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const firstOperation = (word) => word
const secondOperation = (word) => new Promise(
  (resolve) => setTimeout(
    () => resolve(word), 
    1000
  )
)

const operations = [firstOperation('Hello'), firstOperation('World'), firstOperation('How'), secondOperation('Are'), firstOperation('you'), firstOperation('today')]

Promise.all(operations).then(word => console.log(word))
```